# Найти и получить слово из строки

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, как я могу найти в строке слово начинающееся с двоеточия (:word).
Есть строка, например:

```
$stroka = 'Once upon a time in granny, two gay goose. One :gray, the other :white. Two happy geese.';
```

Нужно получить слово 'gray' и 'white' и занести в массив.

Как возможно это реализовать. Полагаю preg_match мне в помощь, но не соображу, как составить регулярку.
Полагаю так: `preg_match('/[:][A-z]/'` но, как занести в массив слова то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так?

```
$stroka = 'Once upon a time in granny, two gay goose. One :gray, the other :white. Two happy geese.';

preg_match_all('/(?<=:)\w+/', $stroka, $words, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$matches = $words[0];

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Спасибо. А подскажите есть ли возможность записывать значения не во вложенный массив, а просто массив?
Массив вложенного вида: array(array()) не подходит.

Comment: Подредактировал, теперь на выходе простой массив.

Comment: нет, это понятно, что можно через ключ массив внутренний получить. Я просто имею ввиду возможно ли вообще получить массив сразу простой?